# Click event counter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, image, dom, getelementbyid, addeventlistener

I've read through a lot of questions and most seem to lead over to JQuery, but I'm actually trying to get this working using just vanilla JS.  I'm trying to get the screen number beneath the picture to increase by 1 with each click.  I've actually gotten NaN and now a weird "[objectParagraphElement]1" message when I click, so I know the DOM is being impacted.  Can somebody see something silly I'm doing?

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
    <title>KittyKlikr</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<!--<p id="kitty"></p>-->
<span id="kitty1"><img src="kittyklikr.jpg" alt="kitty" height="50%" width="50%"></span>
<br>
<p id="counter">0</p>
<script>
document.addEventListener("click", addUp, false);
function addUp() {
    var x = document.getElementById("counter");
    document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = x+1;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given you have:

```
var x = document.getElementById("counter");
```

and that the *innerHTML* property returns a string, you need to convert the value to a number, add 1, then write back to the element:

```
x.innerHTML = parseInt(x.innerHTML) + 1;
```

Or you can use the [*unary + operator*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6):

```
x.innerHTML = +x.innerHTML + 1;
```

but [*parseInt*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.25) might be clearer.

#### Edit

BTW, a much cleaner approach is to store the value as a Number and write it to the element, e.g.:

```
// Use an IIFE to hold count and reference to element in a closure
var addUp = (function() {
  var count = 0;

  return function () {
    var element = document.getElementById("counter");
    if (element) element.innerHTML = ++count;
  }
}());

// Attach as a listener
document.addEventListener("click", addUp, false);
```

Note that since a function expression is used, you can't assign it as a listener until after the expression has executed.

Answer (score 0):

You need `document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = Number(x.innerHTML) + 1;`, not `document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = x + 1;`.

You are adding 1 to the element, not the element's value.

Comment: Seems neither method above is returning anything other than NaN.  Now, I am using Cloud9 on my Chromebook, and this is through a tiny preview window so not sure if the code really is the issue.